# Chrome v70+ has issue with innerText in td cells

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

This was working in v69 and lower.

Every innerText value of a cell before the last has a trailing character.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/L16x9gpe/

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
    <tr id='row'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I have raised an issue with Chromium development here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=897373 It seems all browsers at the moment do not contain the trailing character issue, including Firefox where the original specification apparently was derived. The commit author Yoshifumi Inoue (yosin@chromium.org) has stated this should be the correct implementation. I think it should act like other browsers and not have this differentiating behavior. The whatwg spec should be changed to be more specific and only include a trailing tab character (U+0009) for table or row innerText calls instead of a direct call to a td cell.

Comment: Thanks @brg for documenting and chasing this up! The change is breaking some small parts of our Intranet site, for multiple users, as the Chrome update rolls out across our organisation. The .trim() fix works, of course. Very much agree with your suggestion (which seems to be in the process of being accepted) that the innerText of a single `td` should not append anything, but when selecting something with multiple `td`s it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same problem. The workaround I'm using for now is changing my code to `cell.innerText.trim()`.

Comment: .innerText.trim() or .textContent is the solution to use until Chrome puts out a better fix

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Chrome team "fixed a glitch" that hadn't been working correctly, according to the standard (based on the link below). 
This caught me off-guard with an inherited application, as well.

[innerText functionality](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/dom.html#dom-htmlelement-innertext)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing some simple text comparison, so I switched to .innerHTML because it seems to not have the same tab/LF append requirements that .innerText has.

In my case, the cells don't have any HTML in them. I thought that .innerText was more clear that I only wanted the text. But, I guess, if you are converting table cells to text you would want to have those separator characters.

Answer (score 0):

This broke an extension I wrote for a client. I was checking cells[blah].innerText == 'somevalue', and those checks became false with the update when they should be true.

Changing innerText to textContent fixed it, which is counter-intuitive, because textContent is supposed to preserve whitespace the same as a pre tag, and innerText is supposed to just get you the text.